# MongoRepository.save doesn't throw duplication key exception

Tags: spring, mongodb, exception

In my spring boot application(kotlin) I use spring mongo data.
If I call save method to insert new document with the same id, I can see in the log that there was an exception(duplication key) but the method save doesn't thorw it, so I cant catch it.
It seams that the exception is caught inside save() method, logged and never thrown again
everything works ok when I call insert instead of save, insert methods comes from MongoRepository and save from CrudeRepository. could it be a bug in Spring?

```
interface EmailMngRepository : MongoRepository<EmailInfo, String> 
...

try {
    val ret=emailRepo.save(EmailInfo("email@com"))//
}
catch (ex:org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyExceptionDuplicateKeyException){
    ///it never goes here
}
```

ret contains object EmailInfo and program continue, why???

below there is the same code but with insert method.(works)

```
try {
        val ret=emailRepo.insert(EmailInfo("email@com"))
    }
    catch (ex:org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyExceptionDuplicateKeyException){
        //now i can catch exception
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the field as @Id or unique field.

```
@Id
private String email;
```

or

```
@Indexed(unique=true)
private String email;
```

Comment: @Id is defined, as I said the problem is that I can see the exceptions in the logs but it is not thorw outside the save method, when using inset() then it works as expected.